# Simpler, Cleaner Inline Links [JADE Preprocessing]

Tags: html, preprocessor, pug

I wish to write the following simple html in [Jade](http://jade-lang.com/):

`<p>Nevertheless, you can read his stuff on his nameless <a href="blog">blog</a> as well as on the <a href="voice">Voice</a> college blog.</p>`

An ugly, long, error-prone way of doing this is:

```
p Nevertheless, you can read his stuff on his nameless 
    a(href="blog") blog
    |  as well as on the 
    a(href="voice") Voice
    |  college blog.
```

Is there an easier / simpler way of writing this? Thanks

**Edit:** Please ignore the code highlighting colours as they have no significance.

Answer (score 0):

The quickest way is to break out of jade and into markdown, see more here: [Jade: Links inside a paragraph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6989653/jade-links-inside-a-paragraph)