# In a Jade template how do I put a literal URL as a link anchor?

Tags: pug

In a Node.js Express web app, I would like to include a link to some documentation in one of my views, and show the URL as the anchor text. Following [Jade: Links inside a paragraph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6989653/jade-links-inside-a-paragraph), I tried:

```
p See #[a(href="http://example.com/help/123") http://example.com/help/123]
```

However, that causes an error, `"The end of the string was reached with no closing bracket found."`

If I put quotes around the anchor text, it mostly works, but I end up with quotes visible in the HTML output, which I don't want.

```
p See #[a(href="http://example.com/help/123") "http://example.com/help/123"]
```

Is something about the unquoted URL messing up the evaluation of the stuff inside the brackets? If so, can I escape it somehow to prevent the problem?

Comment: Seems like a bug to me. I've narrowed it down to this not working either: `p #[p :/]`. So the string `:/` (colon forward-slash) inside a nested tag `#[]` causes the error. edit: opened an [issue on jade gh](https://github.com/jadejs/jade/issues/2144)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a variable:

```
-var helpurl="http://example.com/help/123"
p See #[a(href=helpurl) #{helpurl}]
```

<del>The double slash in the URL itself is probably being interpreted as the start of a comment, and preventing the evaluator from reading the rest of the expression, including its closing bracket.</del>

**EDIT**: From the issue kindly opened by @laggingreflex (https://github.com/jadejs/jade/issues/2144), It is actually the colon-slash sequence that is problematic prior to Jade 2.0.0. For those using earlier versions, the Jade author ForbesLindesay recommends using equals-sign evaluation of a literal string.

```
p See #[a(href="http://example.com/help/123")= "http://example.com/help/123"]
```